# python-Convert a returned string which has " and \" both in it to dict

Tags: python

I got a returned string value

```
returned_string = '{"url":"src=\"http:the_url\""}'
```

and I want to convert it to a dictionary type.
When I try eval(),following error appears:

> File "", line 1
>       {"url":"src="http:the_url""}
>                       ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I try json.loads(),following error appears:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 14 (char 13)

I know if the string is like this:

```
returned_string = r'{"url":"src=\"http:the_url\""}'
```

then both eval() and json.loads() work. But as the value name tells ,it's a string which is returned by some function() , so I cant transform it to r'..' or I just don't know how.
So,It will be really helpful if anyone know how to convert returned_string to a dictionay.Thanks.

Comment: what should be the expected result ? i don't see and `,` in string to indicate more than one key.   is this expected result  `{"url":"src","http":"theurl"}` or `{"url":"src=http:theurl"}` ?

Comment: The expected result should be:
{"url":"src='http:the_url'"} or {'url': 'src="http:the_url"'}  and its type should be dict

Comment: What is this "some function"? It is clearly buggy if it is producing the above output, and the output is meant to be valid json or a valid python dict literal. Perhaps you could change its arguments?

Comment: @Dunes  you can consider it as a function which extracts a string-type dictionary from a html source code.i.e. ".....var data={"url":"src=\"http:the_url\""}...." in html source code,then I extracted '{"url":"src=\"http:the_url\""}' from it AKA returned_string

Comment: That sounds reasonable, and should handle the slash correctly. I think the key part is how are you doing the extraction? That's the bit that sounds like it needs to be fixed. That is, what happens when you do `print(returned_string)`? I'm expecting the slashes will have disappeared. Your extraction method needs to make sure it preserves these slashes as they are important.

Comment: @Dunes When I do print(returned_string), it actually shows `'{"url":"src="http:the_url""}'` with no slashes in it, but still error when using eval()  or json.loads()  to convert it.  I believe the string of the initial return is what it is( part of html source code),we need to the "  between "     ".

Comment: Sorry. Your last sentence doesn't make sense to me. The slashes are important and must be preserved. So try to find the bit of code that is losing the slashes. In essence, what I am saying is that you could try a trick to decode this bad JSON (like you've asked), or could you track down the code that is producing the bad JSON. The second is much more preferable.

Comment: OK, I'll try to rewrite my extracting function and see if that could help solving the problem.Thanks

Comment: **@Lunam**, I've found the way now so that your code will perfectly work with `eval()`. Now I'm checking for `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 0):

**@Lunam**, let you first have a look at the below code executed on Interactive terminal.

```
>>> returned_string = '{"url":"src=\"http:the_url\""}'
>>> returned_string2 = '{"url":"src=\'http:the_url\'"}'
>>>
>>> json.loads(returned_string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\rishi\Anaconda2\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\rishi\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\rishi\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
  obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 14 (char 13)
>>>
>>> json.loads(returned_string2)
{u'url': u"src='http:the_url'"}
>>>
>>> eval(returned_string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1
  {"url":"src="http:the_url""}
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> eval(returned_string2)
{'url': "src='http:the_url'"}
>>>
```

Now, modify your string manually/prgamatically as below i.e. use `"""` to surround your string, remove `\`, use `'` inside `"` and try.

> Please let me know if it doesn't satisfy your problem.

```
import json

# returned_string = '{"url":"src=\"http:the_url\""}'
returned_string = """{"url":"src='http:the_url'"}"""

print(json.loads(returned_string))
print(eval(returned_string))
```

#### Output

```
{'url': "src='http:the_url'"}
{'url': "src='http:the_url'"}
```

Comment: ,thx,I know if """ is added around my string or " is replaced by ' ,then eval() and json.loads() both will work. And here comes the problem,  the string is returned by a function,so I cant modify it manually,and I dont know how to change it by code.Would u plz show me how to do it? Many thanks

Comment: Let me find a way to do this. Please add few more outputs that you can get as response with expected outputs. At least 2 or 3. I will check and write code for it. Many thanks for responding back with a nice question.

Comment: It's like :
'{"a":" \"keyisa\" "}' - <class 'str'>  >>>     {"a":" 'keyisa' "}  - <class 'dict'>                              
, '{"b":"  \"bvalue\"  "}'  - <class 'str'>   >>>  {"b":" 'bvalue' "} -<class 'dict'>
I hope the two can make understand more clear.
Actually it's just an issue about how to deal with \" in the string when processing it to a dictionary

Comment: Okay fine. I will get back to you with a new comment once finished (I find a way). Thanks.

Comment: Your string contains `=` or not, as you have specified in the main problem? If it contains then paste real return values. Actually I am going to use regular expression for match and replace operations.

Comment: because the real return values is too long, here is part of it `'{"embedCode": "<iframe src=\"https:\/...\" frameborder=\"0\" ><\/iframe>"}'`, if you can help me convert it to `{"embedCode": "<iframe src=\"https:\/...\" frameborder=\"0\" ><\/iframe>"}`-- <class 'dict'>,that will solve my problem.Thanks